# How to display desired date and time when accessing timestamp object using node-pg

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, date, node-postgres

I am accessing the `timestamp` object from a database using `node-pg` `pool.query()` and displaying it on a web page using the following code within an `ejs` file:

```
<%= obj.date %>
```

The result is `Fri Aug 13 2021 08:22:18 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time)` which is not how I want it to be displayed (in my database this value is stored as `2021-08-13 08:22:18`. I've tried using `JSON.stringify` as follows:

```
<%= JSON.stringify(obj.date) %>
```

But I get the following result  `"2021-08-13T12:22:18.179Z"`. How am I able to get the time value to be displayed as `T08:22:18`  instead of  `T12:22:18`? I'm assuming that it is using a different timezone when calling `JSON.stringify` for some reason but I just don't understand why it wouldn't stay as the time displayed in the database and in the `obj.date` variable.

Comment: The problem with `timestamp` is that it doesn't know anything about timezones, so JS has to assume your local timezone when creating the `new Date`. `JSON.stringify` always outputs the UTC time of that point in time.

Comment: Are there any work arounds for this? For example is there anyway to explicitly state your time zone so it doesn't automatically output UTC time?

Comment: Sure, use `.toString()` and the like instead of `.toUTCString()` and the like (which `JSON.stringify` uses). But there is no method that outputs exactly the format you want, you'll need to put that together yourself.

Comment: If you want to store the local time, then you should also store the offset: "2021-08-13T08:22:18GMT-0400", otherwise it will be treated as local so be a different moment in time for each host with a different offset.